# Painting with polygons in BLender 2.8 - help needed

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, displacement

I've been intrigued with paining with polygons effect - info below:

[image]

http://www.isaacbotkin.com/siggraph/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-I0hRymkhnQ&t=592s

I have tried to recreate this in Blender 2.8. 
First I have created shader with displacement using texture offset:

[image]
After this I used linear interpolation and cycling over frame 0 and 1 with changing texture mapping rotation:

[image]

After that I tried rendering (In cycles) but it doesn't work. I am at loss what do next.

I have found one topic about this but it is from 2009 so not actual: https://blenderartists.org/t/painting-with-polygons/453991/7

I also found a guy who uploaded a working blend file, but it is for version 2.63 and I haven'T been able to recreate it. It can be found here:
http://rylanwright.blogspot.com/2012/09/sharing-fun.html

Finally, here is my blend file:
https://pasteall.org/blend/2706155074d9419da210ebd9950097e6

I would be very thankful if someone could help me to work this out, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to recreate painting with polygons by using the ideas from this paper.
http://www.isaacbotkin.com/siggraph/

Here is my result:
[image]

To achieve the hand painted look by motion blur, i used the displacement modifier
and did a variation of the "Strength" over time.

[image]

Also i did a little rotation of the monkey head during rendering a single frame.

To get the oszillation of the object during rendering, i defined this in the Dope Sheet
so that the oszillation is performed multiple times during one frame.
[image]

Then i activated motion blur inside the Render Tab.

[image]

For a stronger representation of the blur effekt raise Diffuse value at Light Path settings.

[image]

At least i used a brush stroke Bump Map and a Gradient Texture node setup.
[image]

For the rendering i used a frame rate 25ps

[image]

and a render sampling rate of 600 and Pixel Filter 3

[image]